# How to retain soft keyboard state after invalidateOptionsMenu android

Tags: android, keyboard, android-actionbar

Hi I have used searchview like below,

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_menu, menu);
        SearchManager manager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(manager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        searchTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        try {
            Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
            mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
            mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.cursor); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        }
        mMenu = menu;
        setNotificationCount(mMenu);
    }
```

and i'm invalidating notification count using the below code,

```
 getSupportActionBar().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

but invalidating the menu will close the opened keyboard. I want to retain the keyboard state even after invalidate the action bar menus. So I have tried to retain keyboard state using below code,

```
 KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(getActivity(), new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                            if(!isFristTime){
                                Log.d("ss","keyboard status before validated "+isKeyboardOpened);
                                isKeyboardOpened = isOpen;
                                isFristTime = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    getSupportActionBar().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                    Log.d("ss","keyboard status after validated "+isKeyboardOpened);
                    if(isKeyboardOpened){
                        final Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Log.d("ss","keyboard status in try ");
                                    Field mCursorDrawableRes = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
                                    mCursorDrawableRes.setAccessible(true);
                                    mCursorDrawableRes.set(searchTextView, R.drawable.cursor); //This sets the cursor resource ID to 0 or @null which will make it visible on white background
                                    BDevice.showSoftKeyboard(getActivity(), searchTextView);
                                    isKeyboardOpened = false;
                                    getSupportActionBar().invalidateOptionsMenu();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.d("ss","keyboard status in catch ");
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                    }
```

But this will not work. Now I want to open the soft keyboard if its opened before invalidating the menu. Could you please suggest me an idea to retain the keyboard state after invalidate the menu?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Whenever validating the action bar menu onCreateOptionsMenu gets call. So I have store the keyboard state very first time the keyboard gets opened and checking the keyboard state in onCreateOptionsMenu  after validating it. Then i use to expand the searchview and open the soft keyboard programmatically like below,

Global variables

```
private boolean isFristTime = false, isKeyboardOpened = false;
private String mCurrentQuery = "";
```

Then my code in onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
 if(isKeyboardOpened) {
                searchView.setIconified(false);
                searchItem.expandActionView();
                searchView.requestFocus();
                if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mCurrentQuery)){
                    searchView.setQuery(mCurrentQuery, false);
                }else{
                    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search));
                }
                searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
                BDevice.showSoftKeyboard(getActivity(), searchTextView);
                isKeyboardOpened = false;
            }
```

and i'm getting my keyboard start before validation like below,

```
KeyboardVisibilityEvent.setEventListener(getActivity(), new KeyboardVisibilityEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean isOpen) {
                            if(!isFristTime){

                                isKeyboardOpened = isOpen;
                                isFristTime = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    getSupportActionBar().invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

and getting my query inside the onQueryTextChange method

```
   @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
           mCurrentQuery = newText;
          return true;
        }
```

Happy Coding...